# Active attribute for Bootstrap UI won't display correct content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my Angular app, I am using the bootstrap `ui.bootstrap` module. Through out the site I have had to use my own custom `ul` to act as the tab buttons to display the specified content. Like so:

```
<ul class="nav phase-pills">
    <li ng-click="activeTab = 0;>Green</li>
    <li ng-click="activeTab = 1;>Amber</li> //user clicks. activeTab has value of 1
    <li ng-click="activeTab = 2;>Red</li>
    <li ng-click="activeTab = 3;">Blue</li>
</ul>

<uib-tabset active="activeTab" type="pills"> //activeTab
    <uib-tab heading="Green" index="0" class="bg-phase-green font-body" ng-hide="true"> //ng-hide hides this tab and my own list item can act as the tab
        //content   
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Amber" index="1" ng-hide="true"> // index 1.. displays
        //content   
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Red" index="2" ng-hide="true">
        //content       
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Blue" index="3" ng-hide="true">
        //content   
    </uib-tab>                  
</uib-tabset>
```

On click, `activeTab` is updated with the specified value, and displays the corresponding content.

I have now had to use `ng-repeat` to display custom tabs, which shouldn't cause issues, as I am associating an index value from the controller like so:

```
vm.activityNotifications = [
    {
        activity: 'Stage Change',
        index: '0'
    },
    {
        activity: 'Transactions',
        index: '1'
    },
    {
        activity: 'Renewals',
        index: '2'
    }
]

<ul class="nav btn-default view-pills">
    <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.activityNotifications"
         ng-click="$ctrl.setActivityActiveTab(item.activity); 
                   activeActivityTabResp = item.index"
        ng-class="{active : $ctrl.activeMenu == item.activity}">
      <a class="nav-link">{{item.activity}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

One function I have is to add an active class, which is working. When I log the item.index, it displays in the console so it should be displaying the relevant content, but it isn't.

***Question***

Why isn't the tabcontent displaying when a `li` item is clicked from the `ngRepeat`?

```
<uib-tabset type="pills view-pills" active="activeActivityTabResp">
    <uib-tab heading="Stage Change" index="0" ng-hide="true">
        //content       
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Transactions" index="1" ng-hide="true">
        //content       
    </uib-tab>
   <uib-tab heading="Renewals" index="2" ng-hide="true">
        //content
   </uib-tab>   
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Also, try setting the values for `index` property as integer instead of string, e.g `index: 1`.

Comment: I  will try and create a simplified version. I just realised, each custom tab I have created, when I log the index value, they all display `0` the first time, then proceed to log their actual index.... don't know if that would help

Comment: Here's a sample from angular website. You could update this to match your scenario: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` property needs to be an integer.

```
vm.activityNotifications = [
    {
        activity: 'Stage Change',
        index: 0
    },
    {
        activity: 'Transactions',
        index: 1
    },
    {
        activity: 'Renewals',
        index: 2
    }
]
```

Here's a plunker with the implementation: https://plnkr.co/edit/GUVq5Mc3DvaAIITl8sLj?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. Still have an issue of the first logged index being 0 for all 3 items, but it is now still display correct content. Thank you for your time and effort!